# GTK3 not detected in Visual Studio Code - Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, gtk3

Right after installing MSYS2, I already managed to:

1. install the necessary packages mentioned in https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows.
2. included `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` in the Environment Variables.
3. updated the `includePath` in VS Code:

```
 "configurations": [
     {
         "name": "Win32",
         "includePath": [
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0/gtk",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/fribidi",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/lzo",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/pixman-1",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/atk-1.0",
             "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/C++/10.3.0"
         ],
         "defines": [
             "_DEBUG",
             "UNICODE",
             "_UNICODE"
         ],
         "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
         "cStandard": "gnu17",
         "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
         "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
     }
 ],
 "version": 4
}
```

However, this issue always appears:

```
c:2:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I've been stuck with this problem for quite a while now and this is my first time including external libraries so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your `tasks.json` use the same gcc? You may need to add "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0" as an include folder to your compiler.

Comment: Can I ask where to find `tasks.json`? There is only `c_cpp_properties.json` and `settings.json` under the .vscode folder.

Comment: It's normally in the .vscode folder. I think someone else will have to help.